# Observing a Change to ANY Class Property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties, notifications, key-value-observing

Put simply, is there a way to receive a general notification when any property in an Objective-C class is changed? I know I can use KVO to monitor particular property changes, but I have the need to call a particular method whenever any `setProperty:` message is sent to my class. I want to be able to receive a generic notification without any concern about which property in particular was modified.

If it helps to clarify why I want to do this, I am making use of some fast table scrolling code found here: http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

Part of the process of accomplishing this is that whenever a property in a table view cell is modified, `[ self setNeedsDisplay ]` needs to be called. I'd rather not have to override the setter methods for every property in my class just to make this call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Chuck notes, you can create a dependent key, or of course you can directly observe all the properties (which is less work than overloading the setters).

Using the Objective-C runtime, if you exclusively use properties, you can automate this process using [`class_copyPropertyList()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101). But I'd probably only do this if this problem comes up a bit for you. If you only have one instance of this problem, it's probably easier and safer and more maintainable just to directly observe the list of properties unless you feel like working in the ObjC runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example built off of Chuck and Rob's suggestions:

DrakeObject.h

```
@interface DrakeObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *age;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *money;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *startPosition;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentPosition;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) id propertiesChanged;

@end
```

DrakeObject.m

```
@implementation DrakeObject

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.age = @25;
        self.money = @25000000;
        self.startPosition = @"bottom";
        self.currentPosition = @"here";
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)propertiesChanged {
    return nil;
}

+(NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingPropertiesChanged {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"age", @"money", @"startPosition", @"currentPosition", nil];
}
```

observing propertiesChanged will let us know anytime a property has changed.

```
[self.drakeObject addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"propertiesChanged"
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. You can create a [dependent key](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html) that depends on every property you wish to expose and then observe that. That's about as close as you'll get, I think.

Comment: Hm. Seems like I would be abusing the concept of dependent keys in this case. I suppose I'll just observe each property individually. I could have sworn that there was a generic way to do this. How about a way to catch the name of the message being passed to a class via the runtime?

Comment: Not really. Just call the dependent key `propertiesChanged` or something like that and it will be quite accurate. mmalc at Apple actually suggests this technique in his Cocoa Bindings Example and Hints: http://homepage.mac.com/mmalc/CocoaExamples/controllers.html … As for "catching the name of the message being passed to a class", I assume you mean catching *all* messages sent to a class. This would require either a proxy object or hooking into the `objc_msgSend()` runtime function, the latter of which would be massively slow and hackish and really not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of code. I have a general object and dother object. Dother object has to save his state on change each property.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GeneralObject : NSObject

+ (instancetype)instanceWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary;
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue;
- (NSArray *)allPropertyNames;

@end
```

implementation

```
#import "GeneralObject.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation GeneralObject

#pragma mark - Public

+ (instancetype)instanceWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary {
    return [[self alloc] initWithDictionary:aDictionary];
}

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary {
    aDictionary = [aDictionary clean];

    for (NSString* propName in [self allPropertyNames]) {
        [self setValue:aDictionary[propName] forKey:propName];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue {
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *propertyNames = [self allPropertyNames];

    id object;
    for (NSString *key in propertyNames) {
        object = [self valueForKey:key];
        if (object) {
            [result setObject:object forKey:key];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

- (NSArray *)allPropertyNames {
    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        [array addObject:name];
    }

    free(properties);

    return array;
}

@end
```

and after all we have dother class, which should save his state on **each change of any property**

```
#import "GeneralObject.h"

extern NSString *const kUserDefaultsUserKey;

@interface DotherObject : GeneralObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *email;

@end
```

and implementation

```
#import "DotherObject.h"

NSString *const kUserDefaultsUserKey = @"CurrentUserKey";

@implementation DotherObject

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    if (self = [super initWithDictionary:dictionary]) {
        for (NSString *key in [self allPropertyNames]) {
            [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:key options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(nullable NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(nullable id)object change:(nullable NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey, id> *)change context:(nullable void *)context {
    NSDictionary *dict = [self dictionaryValue];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:kUserDefaultsUserKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@; dict:\n%@", [super     description], [self dictionaryValue]];
}

@end
```

Happy coding!