# Observe all property changes of object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Observing a Change to ANY Class Property in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910449/observing-a-change-to-any-class-property-in-objective-c)

I have a object `currentUser` which contains `int`s and `const char*`s and I am trying to implement a logout system. When the logout button is pressed, I want to be able to check if I have made any changes to the object and if so, I want to prompt the user to save before logging out.

In order to do so I think I need to be able to observe the changes, if any, that are made to the object. I considered KVO but I don't know how to observe the entire variable as a key path. Does anybody have any ideas on what I should do? Also if you could post some code as well that would help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your needs but would posting a notification to NSNotificationCenter work?

Comment: No I would need to be able to observe the changes made ti the object as if I didn't know if there any changes made.